# Magefan blog - open graph not showing

Tags: magento2, php, blog

I am using magefan blog extension and documentation says that extension supports facebook open graph. But when I try to share blog content of facebook it shows some random pictures and content and the og meta tags are not showing. The open graph is working on products, when I share them everything is ok, the content, image, and the og meta tags are visible.

I looked everywhere in the settings but I could not find settings for magefan open graph. Can you please point me in the right direction, what am I missing. Thank you all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated my magefan extension and fields for open graph accrued in the post settings page.